# changing redirect_url of authenticate_user helper of rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

By default Devise has an `authenticate_user!` helper. When used in the controller and the user is not authenticated, then it redirects to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in. I want to change the redirect URL when user is not authenticated.
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect to log in page if user is not authenticated with Devise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23555618/redirect-to-log-in-page-if-user-is-not-authenticated-with-devise)

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes