# redirect the users to the sign up page - Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have built a rails application. I have installed Devise for Users registraion and added the `before_action :authenticate_user!` Method, However what this method does is redirect the user who didn't sign up to the login page. What i want is to redirect them to the sign up page instead of the login page.

Here's my code:

**`rails_course_controller.rb`**

```
class RailsCourseController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!


  def railsDashboard
  end

  def getting_started
  end

  def whatisurbyandrails
  end

  def downloadRails
  end

  def windows_download
end

end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect to log in page if user is not authenticated with Devise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23555618/redirect-to-log-in-page-if-user-is-not-authenticated-with-devise)

Comment: Also; Ruby is using `snail_casing`, not `camelCasing`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the default behavior of the `:authenticate_user!` method. In your `application_controller.rb` add this:

```
protected
def authenticate_user!
  if user_signed_in?
    super
  else
    redirect_to sign_up_path, :notice => 'Please sign up first'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be you can find the answer here:

http://[stackoverflow.com/questions/18903145/how-to-make-sign-up-page-be-root-page-in-devise?rq=1][1]