# Rails Devise: calling super inside authenticate_group! raises no superclass method `authenticate_group!` in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Devise has a handy feature called `devise_group` (link to [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/Helpers/ClassMethods:devise_group)), which creates a group with your multiple devise models.

The docs are really self explanatory. If you have 2 devise models named, for instance, `Admin` and `User`, you can use `devise_group` like so:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  devise_group :blogger, contains: [:user, :admin]
end
```

This would give you, alongside with `authenticate_user!` and `authenticate_admin!`, the method `authenticate_blogger!`, which would redirect unless **user or admin** were signed in.

We have been using this in production and it works great. We have the flexibility to restrict some Controller/actions to admins using `authenticate_admin!` and use `authenticate_blogger!` when we can have both accessing it.

Due to some complex business logic we have, we had to override `authenticate_user!` in ApplicationController, following this nice StackOverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23585023/1290457).

Basically it proposes to override ApplicationController#authenticate_user! and calling `super` when we want the flow follow trough Devise's.

The problem arose when we tried to do the same solution with `authenticate_blogger!. If we do this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  devise_group :blogger, contains: [:user, :admin]

  def authenticate_blogger!
    super
  end

end

// Another controller

class DashboardController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_blogger!

end
```

Rails raises this error:

```
super: no superclass method `authenticate_blogger!' for #<DashboardController:0x00007fd453ca5d80> Did you mean? authenticate_user!
```

Any idea why calling super inside an override of `authenticate_user!` in ApplicationController works fine, but the same doesn't happen with the devise group equivalent ?

**EDIT 1: found out the reason, but could use some help improving the solution**

Looking at [devise source code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/8b539756522368e6c0581e84ddb982400bb27b9a/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L44), `devise_group` uses Ruby's `class_eval` do define instance methods like `authenticate_blogger!` in the context of the class it was called.

So when we use `devise_group` inside `ApplicationController`, it's like we're defining `authenticate_blogger!` as an instance method in ApplicationController.

That's why when we manually define that method `authenticate_blogger!` in ApplicationController and call `super` it raises the exception, because we actually overwrote the same instance method in the same class (ApplicationController) and there's nothing to find up in the ancestor chain.

`authenticate_user!`, on the other hand, is way up in the ancestor chain in `Devise::Controllers::Helpers` (I can see it calling ApplicationController.ancestors`.

The hacky-proof-of-concept-fix we did was to create a `TempController`, define `devise_group` inside it, and make ApplicationController inherit from it:

```
class TempController < ActionController::Base

  devise_group :advertiser, contains: [:user, :broker]

end

// In application_controller.rb

class ApplicationController < TempController

  def authenticate_blogger!
    super // this now works since it goes up in the ancestor chain and finds authenticate_blogger in TempController
  end

end
```

Even tough I'm happy with my investigation ... any suggestions on fixing this without actually having to make ApplicationController not inherit ActionController::Base, like it's default in Rails?